# Variable colspan and variable columns Implementation in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a data array which contains start and end time along with other information

e.g.
     var data = [

```
 {"start": 12:00, "end": 12:27, "title": "alpha", "description": "bla bla    bullshit"},
 {"start": 12:27, "end": 13:20, "title": "beta", "description": "bla bla bullshit1"},
 {"start": 13:20, "end": 13:50, "title": "gama", "description": "bla bla bullshit2"},
 {"start": 13:50, "end": 15:00, "title": "cat", "description": "bla bla bullshit3"}

  ];
```

There are many data variables and each data variable information needs to be filled in a table tr.

Sample table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th colspan="60">Time:</th>
<th colspan="60">12:30</th>     
<th colspan="60">13:00</th>
<th colspan="60">13:30</th>
<th colspan="60">14:00</th>
<th colspan="60">14:30</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="40">title</td>
<td colspan="30">title</td>     
<td colspan="50">title</td> 
<td colspan="90">title</td> 
<td colspan="100">title</td>    
<td colspan="50">title</td>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="60">title1</td>
<td colspan="30">title2</td>        
<td colspan="40">title3</td>    
<td colspan="100">title4</td>   
<td colspan="130">title5</td>   
 </tr>
</table>
```

Data start and end are time which can vary as minutes.
I tried to use above code but it is not uniform, sometimes colspan of 50 is larger than colspan of 90.
Header would always be same.

Kindly help..stuck for a very long time.
If instead of table i should use any other tag please suggest.

Purpose is to make epg like this
http://gonedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/PhilipsEPG1.jpg

http://www.abload.de/img/grmulepgumu7m.jpg

Comment: You realize what colspan means, right? It implies that your first row has 360 columns. Makes little sense. Especially, when the next one has 320, but in reality both rows have only 6.

Comment: Every row has span of 360 that is fixed. I realize what colspan means.  
Thanks for response.Can u suggest ny other method.

Comment: It sould not be table to start from. Use div containers positioned absolutely relatively to parent, with specific width depending on event duration.

Comment: The sum of the colspans should always be the same per row.

Comment: @dfsq: Can you please provide one example?

Comment: @oMiKeY: It is same still they vary. Sometimes colspan 30 is larger than colspan 60.